# dynamic time warping (DTW) algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to understand the so called [DTW algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).

What's the meaning of the following?

```
for i := 1 to n
   DTW[i, 0] := infinity
```

And how the is different from the below?

```
for i := 1 to m
   DTW[0, i] := infinity
```

Comment: Those "index zero" row and column are defined just so that you don't need to add exceptions to the recursive formula when you iterate over the actual first row and first column (and you actually can only look left or only look up). When the "index zero" row and column are defined, you can also look at those "forbidden" cells, without adding exceptions, but you'll see there `infinity`, so your algorithm will never select them. You might want to take a look at this simple Python implementation: https://github.com/talcs/simpledtw

Comment: This project's documentation could help you: https://github.com/talcs/simpledtw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array is filled with very large value. It simplifies comparisons in the main algorithm cycle.

In practice one could use constant like `MaxInt`  for integer values (`2^31-1` for `int32`) or `Inf/Math.Infinity` (positive infinity) for floats (special value of ieee 754 float numbers standard that's larger that any real value)

Edit: These two loops fill the first column and the first row of the table.

Comment: I lightly modified the question. May I ask to adjust the answer?